# I'm getting no audio signal from Scarlett 2i4 into Ardour 6 on Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, 20.04, ubuntu-studio, jack, ardour

I recently installed Ardour 6.0.0 (as a download from the Ardour website) in Kubuntu 20.04, using Ubuntu Studio Installer to add packages and configurations.  I also have Mixbux32C-6.0.0 and Ardour 5.12 running.  Using a Scarlett 2i4, I can easily get an audio signal into Ardour 5.12.  However, though I can see the Scarlett in the Mixer setup, I do not get any response in either Ardour 6 or Mixbus32C-6.  I checked the routing in both of the latter applications to be sure that I was actually connected to the Scarlett, and it appears that I am.  Both Mixbus and Ardour 6 work fine otherwise.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Considering Ardour 6 nor Mixbus 32C are not in the Ubuntu repositories, they not supported. Please check with Ardour at ardour.org for support.

Comment: @ErichEickmeyer Questions about third-party packages in Ubuntu are also supported at Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ErichEickmeyer I asked here because I read on the Ardour discussion group (I think) that routing is in the purview of the OS.  Having said that, I am planning to ask the same question of the Ardour group.

Comment: @ErichEickmeyer    As an additional piece of information, I actually installed Kubuntu 20.04, then used the Ubuntu Studio installer to convert Kubuntu to Ubuntu Studio.  I don't know if this made a difference or not.  If it is a problem, I will gladly install Ubuntu Studio directly and just wait for 20.10 to get onto the KDE desktop (which I do like, BTW).

And I actually did search both Ardour and Ask Ubuntu for an answer before I asked the question here.  I always research first, and only ask as a last resort.

Comment: @Nicled  "I recently installed Ardour 6.0.0 (as a download from the Ardour website) in Ubuntu Studio 20.04." ...  "I actually installed Kubuntu 20.04, then used the Ubuntu Studio installer to convert Kubuntu to Ubuntu Studio..." That's not how it works. Using Ubuntu Studio Installer simply puts Ubuntu Studio inside of Kubuntu, not magically transform your installation medium.

Source: I'm the Ubuntu Studio project leader.

Comment: @ErichEickmeyer.  Sorry, my mistake.  I'll try to be more exact next time.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Ardour that Jack is set as Backend.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem I was having with Ardour 6.  In both Ardour 4 and Ardour 5, one could see the strength of the signal going into a track by connecting the track to the proper input (for example, USB interface), then doing whatever to cause a signal (sing into a microphone, strum a guitar, play a note on a keyboard or bass, etc.)  There was no need to arm the track in order to see a response.  Apparently there was some change made to Ardour 6 whereby one must arm the track in order to see a response on the meter on the track.  Once I armed the track, I easily saw a response to the input into my USB device.  I did not have to use either JACK or Carla; it worked with ALSA.